# Modernizr Adding Empty Class to HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, frontend, modernizr

I'm trying to use Modernizr for the first time, and I'm having trouble getting it to add a class to the HTML tag per the Docs.

I used Modernizr's build feature to generate a custom js file to test compatibility for the CSS Object Fit property. I added the file, called `modernizr-custom.js`, to my Javascript directory and, using Gulp, am loading it via my gulpfile. Now when I refresh and open chrome dev tools I see that the HTML tag now has an empty class: `class=" "` instead of `class="object-fit"`. This tells me that Modernizr is doing *something*, but obviously this isn't correct.

I have the `modernizr-config.json` in my root, which is set as follows:

```
{
  "minify": true,
  "options": [
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": [
    "css/objectfit"
  ]
}
```

Should I be loading any additional Modernizr js files for this to work properly? Any insight would be wonderful, as I'm sure I'm just not fully understanding how to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: using the minified file was causing the issue. After the replacing the file with a non-minified file, everything works as expected.